# SELECT data from a 'messages' table, no error but it isn't working. MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to have an array of data that I can pull out from my table like that:

```
echo $message_data['content'];
```

so I declare $message_data like that:

```
     $message_data = message_data($_GET['id'],'id' ,'content', 'sender', 'addressee','support','date');
```

And the message_data() function is written like that:

```
function message_data($message_id) {
$data = array();
$message_id = (int)$message_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if($func_num_args > 1)
{
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    $fields = '`'  .  implode('`, `' , $func_get_args) . '`';
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = $message_id") or die(mysql_error()));
    return $data;
} }
```

This function does work similarly when I try to pull data about the user, I just copied and pasted it and tweaked it slightly.
The problem is, there are no errors, and yes, I do input the browser with a GET variable.
Where is the error? Or if there is a better way to do this, I'd be glad to hear.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should try to dump the query to the page so that you can verify that it's working as you expect. You can even run that query in a query browser to see if the results are coming up that way.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @MihaiIorga, Thanks, I'm going to read about this. and Aaron, the query works when I write:
SELECT `id` , `content` , `sender` , `addressee` , `support` ,`date`
FROM `messages`
WHERE `id` =1, and this is supposed to be the query in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = $message_id") or die(mysql_error()));
```

This line is the issue, inside the brackets it seems foo() or bar() equals to foo() || bar(), it's not what you want, so put it out side like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `messages` WHERE `id` = $message_id") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

edit:

Just don't use or like this, or at least don't use the return value of the or like that.

Normally,

```
A or B
```

if A is false, then PHP will check B; if A is true, then there's no need to check B.

but I guess

```
$c = A or B
```

is actually

```
($c = A) or B
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, but can you tell me why it worked? isn't it the same?